# Check if variable contains any characters in array

Tags: javascript, filenames

I have the following JavaScript, to disallow a file being named a *specific* name, and to disallow certain characters from appearing *anywhere* in the name:

```
var file = 'somefile';
var contain = ['"', '*', ':', '<', '>', '?', '\\', '/', '|', '+', '[', ']'];
var fullname = ['AUX', 'COM1', 'COM2', 'COM3', 'COM4', 'COM5', 'COM6', 'COM7',
  'COM8', 'COM9', 'CON', 'LPT1', 'LPT2', 'LPT3', 'LPT4', 'LPT5', 'LPT6', 'LPT7',
  'LPT8', 'LPT9', 'NUL', 'PRN'];

if(fullname.indexOf(file.toUpperCase()) >= 0)
{
    alert('Your file must not be named any of these words:\n\n' +
      fullname.join(' '));
    return;
}

if(/* file contains any chars in contain[] */)
{
    alert('Your file name must not contain any of these characters:\n\n' +
      contain.join(' '));
    return;
}
```

I'm wondering how I can check if `file` contains any of the items in the `contain` array.

I could use a `for` loop, like so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < contain.length; i++)
    if(file.indexOf(contain[i]) >= 0)
        ...
```

But it seems "wrong" to use a loop for this.

Is there any built-in function to do this using vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: @Peter You've misunderstood the question. That's exactly what I'm already doing in the first `if`. The 2nd `if` is a completely different question.

Comment: Sorry you're right, I've jumped to a conclusion too quickly :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `.indexOf()` then the loop is the only way to go.

However, you could use also a regex:

```
var contain = /["*:<>?\\/|+\[\]]/;
var fullname = /^(AUX|COM1|...)$/i;   // NB: "i" flag for case insensitive

if (contain.test(file)) {
    ...
}

if (fullname.test(file)) {
    ...
}
```

This ought to be pretty efficient as the regex will be processed in native code within the JS interpreter.

Comment: This is great, thanks! Do the `?`, `|`, `+`, `[` and `]` also need to be escaped? (I know these have special meanings in RegEx). Also, I presume the `/` should be escaped, since this signifies the end of the RegEx?

Comment: No, within a character class (`[...]`) some other characters that usually have a special meaning do not.  I tested the above regex and it compiles and appears to work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for that! Also, how can I get the error messages to still work? `contain.join(' ')` obviously fails, since `contain` is now a RegEx, not an array. I guess I need to maintain 2 sets of each? A RegEx and an array?

Comment: ah, hadn't really spotted the `join` bit.  One approach would be to _start_ with the arrays, and then build the regexes from them, i.e. `var fullnameRe = new RegEx('(' + join('|', fullname) + ')', 'i')`

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. The `fullname` check works perfectly, but the error isn't firing for the `contain` check. Would you mind having a quick look for me? http://jsfiddle.net/UcLsR/

Comment: Apparently they do need escaping: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/10753224#10753224

Comment: @DannyBeckett I said _some_ characters, not _all_ characters.  Note that in my code above the backslash, `[` and `]` characters _are_ escaped.

Comment: I also had to change `/(AUX|COM1|...)/i` to `/^(AUX|COM1|...)$/i` since `com1fdfgfg` was being wrongly matched.

Comment: Ah, so you wanted the whole filename to match, not just a substring.  That would be the correct change, then.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered regular expressions for this?

Your code would be like so:

```
var file = 'somefile';

document.body.style.background = "#4f4";


var contain = ['"', '*', ':', '<', '>', '?', '\\', '/', '|', '+', '[', ']'];
var fullname = ['AUX', 'COM1', 'COM2', 'COM3', 'COM4', 'COM5', 'COM6', 'COM7',
  'COM8', 'COM9', 'CON', 'LPT1', 'LPT2', 'LPT3', 'LPT4', 'LPT5', 'LPT6', 'LPT7',
  'LPT8', 'LPT9', 'NUL', 'PRN'];

if(fullname.indexOf(file.toUpperCase()) >= 0)
{    
    alert('Your file must not be named any of these words:\n\n' +
        fullname.join(' '));
    return;
}

// If you want to keep the invalid characters as a array:
var containAsString = contain.join("").replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');

// the reg expression will look like "[;\.]"
var re = new RegExp("["+ containAsString +"]");

if(re.test(file))
{    
    alert('Your file name must not contain any of these characters:\n\n' +
      contain.join(' '));
    return;
}
```

[test it](http://jsfiddle.net/guVYz/)

edit: The accepted answer is obviously cleaner but at least this answer now respect SO policy

Comment: Mr.Pe, this is not an answer. Even if it's a way to solve this is a question, and that's why the downvotes.

Comment: Thank you Sergio. I'll add an example.